# What is a simple way to secure a directory in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, security

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Secure against what? Dinosaurs?

Comment: yeah like dinosaurs, but also only available to admin ppl

Comment: Slaks asks a valid question.  Things you might be concerned about in the context of security: Man in the middle attacks, eavesdropping on connections to the directory, access to the directory by unauthorized users, access to the directory by external computers, access to the directory by unauthorized  machines, access to the directory by dinosaurs, access to the directory by whitelisted search engines.  Depending on your concern, different solutions are appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

In your web.config, you can use the following:

```
<location path="AdminDirectory">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Administrators"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

See here: [msft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871).

Comment: You also need to set up auth and roles.

Answer (score 0):

You can use forms authentication which allows you to specify if authenticated users can access pages by groups.

Unless of course you mean "real" directories that contain files.  What are you securing?  The file system, or the paths to the pages?

Comment: I would like to password protect a directory called /admin